# Linq To SQL throws has no supported translation to SQL Exception when using generic Insert method

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity

I have a method to insert entity to tables genericly using type T. But I want to add a feature to check if the entity to be added exists in the table based on a matcher property (e.g Name). When I execute the code it throws 'has no supported translation to SQL' on the check line. My code part is below. How can I fix this problem?

```
    public static InsertStatus Add<T>(T ent, string matcherProp) where T : class
    {
        System.Data.Linq.Table<T> t = otdc.GetTable<T>();

        //Exception on this line
        if (t.Any(item => object.Equals(GetPropValue(item, matcherProp), GetPropValue(ent, matcherProp))))
            return InsertStatus.AlreadyExists;

        try
        {
            t.InsertOnSubmit(ent);
            otdc.SubmitChanges();
            return InsertStatus.Successfull;
        }
        catch
        {
            return InsertStatus.UnknownError;
        }
    }
    public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }
```

Comment: Your GetPropValue cannot be translated into SQL. You need an `Expression` which your Linq-to-SQL provider understands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create an expresion tree at runtime. Fortunately this isn't very hard in your case; it will be *something like*:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
var val = GetPropValue(ent, matcherProp);
var test = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(p, matcherProp),
        Expression.Constant(val)
    ), p);

if (t.Any(test))
    return InsertStatus.AlreadyExists;
```

What this does is construct the logical tree for:

```
p => p.{matcherProp} == {val}
```

where `matcherProp` is the name of the member to test, and `val` is the existing value as a constant.

Note that you might get issues if `val` is `null`, unless you can also supply the *type* of the property (`.PropertyType` on the `PropertyInfo`) - and supply it to `Expression.Constant`.

---

Edit: another way to do this is to supply `ent` as the constant:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
var test = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.PropertyOrField(p, matcherProp),
        Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(ent), matcherProp),
    ), p);
```

This is then more akin to:

```
p => p.{matcherProp} == ent.{matcherProp}
```

where `ent` in the lambda behaves much like a "captured variable".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `matcherProp` a string, consider making it an `Expression<Func<T, P>>` so you can invoke it as:  `Add(myEntity, e => e.Name)`.

Then you need something like

```
public static InsertStatus Add<T>(T ent, Expression<Func<T,P>> keySelector) where P : class
{
    System.Data.Linq.Table<T> t = otdc.GetTable<T>();

    var memberAccess = (keySelector as LambdaExpression)?.Body as MemberExpression;
    ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(memberAccess.Update(Expression.Constant(ent)), memberAccess.Update(paramExpr)), paramExpr);

    if (t.Any(predicate))
    {
```

With appropriate error checking of course.